# Get-EC2Instance : not authorized to perform this operation

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

```html
Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Join 
        - '-'
        - - !Ref Product
          - !Ref Environment
          - !Ref EnvironmentNo
          - role
          - svn
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'              
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: S3Download
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 's3:GetObject'
                  - ec2:DescribeInstanceAttribute
                  - ec2:DescribeInstances
                  - ec2:DescribeInternetGateways
                  - ec2:DescribeKeyPairs
                  - ec2:DescribeNetworkAcls
                  - ec2:DescribePlacementGroups
                  - ec2:DescribeRegions
                  - ec2:DescribeRouteTables
                  - ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups
                  - ec2:DescribeSnapshotAttribute
                  - ec2:DescribeSnapshots
                  - ec2:DescribeSpotDatafeedSubscription
                  - ec2:DescribeSpotInstanceRequests
                  - ec2:DescribeSpotPriceHistory
                  - ec2:DescribeSubnets
                  - ec2:DescribeTags
                  - ec2:DescribeVolumes
                  - ec2:DescribeVpcs
                  - ec2:DescribeVpnConnections
                  - ec2:DescribeVpnGateways
                  - ec2:GetConsoleOutput
                  - ec2:StartInstances
                  - ec2:RunInstances
                  - ec2:StopInstances
                  - ec2:UnmonitorInstances
                  - ec2:DescribeAddresses               
                Resource:
                  - !Join 
                    - ''
                    - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
                      - !Ref Product
                      - '-'
                      - !Ref Environment
                      - '-'
                      - !Ref EnvironmentNo
                      - '-'
                      - 'bucket'
                      - '-'
                      - 'deployment/common/*'
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 's3:GetObject'
                Resource:
                  - !Join 
                    - ''
                    - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
                      - !Ref Product
                      - '-'
                      - !Ref Environment
                      - '-'
                      - !Ref EnvironmentNo
                      - '-'
                      - 'bucket'
                      - '-'
                      - 'deployment/*'
```

I am running below script from userdata64 launchconfiguration

```
      "$instanceId = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id \n";
       $available = Get-EC2Volume -Filter @{ Name="status"; Values="available" }
       Write-Output $available;
      "Add-EC2Volume -instanceId $instanceId -VolumeId vol-xxxxxxxx -Device /dev/sdb -Region us-west-1\n";
      "Add-EC2Volume -instanceId $instanceId -VolumeId vol-xxxxxxxx -Device /dev/sdc -Region us-west-1\n";
      "Get-Disk | %{ Set-Disk -Number $_.Number -IsOffline $False }\n";
```

As I was getting a unauthorised error"Get-EC2Instance : You are not authorized to perform this operation." so I added all - ec2:Describe* in my policy but still the issue is not fixed. I have gone through so many forums but unable to identify where I am wrong with the IAM policy.

Comment: That's because you set the resource to a bucket. Split the permissions into 2. One for s3:GetObject with the resource you have specified. For the ec2:Describe*, change the resource to either your instance id or to *

Comment: @Krishna Thank you very much for the response.    Is this ok ?                                               Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 's3:GetObject'
                  - ec2:Describe*
                Resource: "*"
  - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 's3:GetObject'
                Resource:

Comment: Take out the s3:GetObject in the first one. The rest of it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

It might be late, but today, I also faced the same Unauthorized issue with Get-EC2Instance call from PowerShell. To get this to work, attach the below 2 permissions to your role policy. Looks like the DescribeNetworkInterfaces permissions is required in addition to DescribeInstances.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}